# FPDF error: Unsupported image type: image/jpeg

Tags: php, html, fpdf

```
if(isset($_POST['sumit']))
  { 

   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","school");
       if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  } 

 $sname=$_POST['sname'];
  $category=$_POST['category'];
 $sadd=$_POST['sadd'];
 $file_name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
  $temp_name=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
  $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
 $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

   $target_path  =  "Newfolder1";
$sql="SELECT * FROM imagetable WHERE   sname='$sname' and sadd='$sadd'and category='$category' and file='$target_path'";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
  if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
                die( "Could not execute sql: $sql"); 
                 }
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($result1);
$file=$row[0];


  $pdf=new fpdf();
$pdf->ADDPage();
$pdf->setfont('Arial','B', 16);

$pdf->Image($file,150,25,50,20,$file_type);


$pdf->Cell(0,10,'id',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'sadd',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'category',0,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'sname',0,1);

$pdf->Output();}
```

This is giving me the image type but all this is being done through database
my image type is being defined in the db but I don't know. I'm gettting the error.
If anyone could find out the error please reply

Comment: What are you getting in `$file` variable? Is it image path?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul yes it is saving the image path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you're specifying the mime type in `$file_type` variable(like `image/png` or `image/jpeg`) and using that in the `Image()` method. You should only specify the image format. Possible values are (case insensitive): JPG, JPEG, PNG and GIF.

So first get the image format, like this:

```
$image_format = strtolower(pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

And then call the `Image()` method like this:

```
$pdf->Image($file,150,25,50,20,$image_format);
```

**Edited:**

Change your `INSERT` query like this,

```
$image_path = $target_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name;
if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $image_path)) { 
    $qry="INSERT INTO imagetable (file, sname, category, sadd, type,size, content ) values ('".$image_path."','".$sname."','".$category."','".$sadd."', '".$file_type."','".$file_size."', '".$Content."')"; 
    mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die("error in $qry == ----> ".mysqli_error()); 
}
```

And change your `SELECT` statement like this,

```
// your code    

$target_path = "Newfolder1" . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $file_name;
$sql="SELECT * FROM imagetable WHERE   sname='$sname' and sadd='$sadd'and category='$category' and file='$target_path'";

// your code
```

Comment: getimagesize(389): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Missing or incorrect image file: 389'

Comment: @IshankSainger Like I asked, what are you getting in `$file` variable? Is it image path?

Comment: @IshankSainger Can you show the image path, which you're getting in the `$file` variable? There's definitely something wrong in that image path.

Comment: when i echo $file; i get id of the latest row

Comment: if(move_uploaded_file($temp_name, "$target_path/$file_name")) {

   $qry="INSERT INTO imagetable (file, sname, category, sadd, type,size, content ) values

('".$target_path."','".$sname."','".$category."','".$sadd."', '".$file_type."','".$file_size."', '".$Content."')";
  mysqli_query($con,$qry) or die("error in $qry == ----> ".mysqli_error());  
  
}

Comment: basicaly file is fetching the target path i,e image path which i have saved in the starting of the code

Comment: @IshankSainger See the point is, the first argument(where you're specifying `$file`) should be path or URL of the image, like this, `process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg`. Can you show a sample image path, which you have under `file` attribute of `imagetable` table?

Comment: file varchar(100) latin1_swedish_ci this is the structure and it is saving file to Newfolder1

Comment: @IshankSainger I meant the image path that's stored in that coumn, not the structure of the column.

Comment: buddy i have mentioned above its Newfolder1 and also see the targetpath in the above code it is same as file , see the select query

Comment: @IshankSainger The problem is you're not storing file name anywhere in the table, are you? In the absence of file name, it would not be possible to get the full path of the image file.

Comment: ohkk no i am saving the path only

Comment: @IshankSainger With this line, `$file=$row[0];` you're only specifying the folder name, not the full path of the image file.

Comment: now i have started storing file name but now iam getting different error         fopen(fbcover.png): failed to open stream: No such file or directory               FPDF error: Can't open image file: fbcover.png

Comment: @IshankSainger I've updated my answer. Please see the **edited** section of my answer.

Comment: i cant believe dis seriously man a bigggggggggggggg thankyou i have been in to dis from last 3 days thank you appreciated your help and tym that u have spent to solve it

Comment: @IshankSainger You're very welcome! Please *accept* the answer if you think it helped you. :)

Comment: buddy can u help me with another problem

Comment: @IshankSainger sure, what is it?

Comment: see iam storing this is a table and dere is a view button in front of every row

Comment: @IshankSainger Please don't edit this question, otherwise it would become unusable for future visitors of Stack Overflow. If your question needs major review or feedback, please form a separate question and ask.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475345/fpdf-error-and-view-table-error no obv not

Comment: this is a gem of a reply obv ia m not gonna ruin it by editing it

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->Image("image/$user-signature.png" ,100, 213,-300);
```

This format works for me. Try removing $file and putting quotes around $filetype

Comment: i dnt know y its not supporting jpeg format  FPDF error: Unsupported image type: image/jpeg

Comment: not working for me and i am wondering do i have to save type field under some different data type other than varchar because its not taking that type image/jpeg or image/png

Comment: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/uploading-files-to-mysql-database.aspx