# fpdf error and view table error

Tags: php, html, mysql, fpdf

[image]

```
 $sqlinsert="SELECT * FROM imagetable "; 
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlinsert);

    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>
              <th>ID</th>            
              <th>School Code</th>
              <th>Category</th>
              <th> School name </th>
              <th> School Address </th> 
              <th> School name </th>

          </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $id=  $row['ID'];
        echo "<tr>
                  <td>";
                  echo $row['ID'];
                  echo "<td>";
                  echo $row['category'];
                  echo "<td>";
                  echo $row['sname'];
                  echo "<td>";
                  echo   $row['sadd'];
                  echo "<td>";
                  echo   $row['filename'];

                  echo "<td>";
                 ?>             


           <form name="form" method="POST" action="parentssubmit.php">
         <input  type="hidden" value="<?php echo  $id;?>" name="search">
         <input type="submit"  value="View" name="View">
       </form>
    <?php   } 

         echo "</td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";
    ========================================================================
    if (isset($_POST['View']) ){
     $pdf=new fpdf();
    $pdf->ADDPage();
    $pdf->setfont('Arial','B', 16);  
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'sname',1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'sadd',1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'category',1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'scode',1,0,'c');


         $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","school");
           if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }


       $file_filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];

       $target_path  =  "Newfolder1";


     $image_path = $target_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "filename";

        $image_format = strtolower(pathinfo('filename', PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $sql="SELECT * FROM imagetable WHERE ID= '$_POST[search]'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
          if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
                    die( "Could not execute sql: $sql"); 
                     }

    // build the data array from the database records.
    While($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
           $pdf->Cell(40,10, $row['sname'],1,0,'c');
            $pdf->Cell(40,10, $row['sadd'],1,0,'c');
            $pdf->Cell(40,10, $row['category'],1,0,'c');


    $pdf->Image($image_path,50,100,50,20,$image_format);

           $pdf->ln();}
    }
    $pdf->output();
```

this is two pages and error is coming out Undefined index:

file Undefined index: file so please try to point out the mistake because main error is showing when i added the image field then the error is started popping out.

- I am trying to fetch the image from the database and trying to show it in PDF format.

Comment: Where exactly you're getting this error? Point out the line where you're getting this error

Comment: First of all close all your `td` tags `echo "</td><td>..."`

Comment: @RajdeepPaul iam getting this error on the second page where  $file_filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];                                                           $pdf->Image($image_path,50,100,50,20,$image_format);

Comment: You're trying to upload files in this form as well? you have no file input and the form is not setup correctly to do this.

Comment: iam trying to fetch the image from database and trying to show it in pdf format

Comment: you also have no `file` name attribute. so the error message `file Undefined index: file` is clear.

Comment: ya that to i noe that is what iam asking what would be the other option for dat

Comment: there's too much that needs to be done, I think you should research more about what you're trying to do

Comment: @ChrisTrudeau brother code was working before i added the image field

Comment: you have been given an answer below. It's out of our hands now.

Comment: @Fred-ii- still thanks bro

Comment: you're welcome. However, if your query contains errors, you should be checking for that also, just in case. Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to `mysqli_query()` and see if anything comes from it. Good luck @IshankSainger

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should close all your `<tr>` and `<td>` tags. Second, you're not sending any file with your form, and hence you're getting this `Undefined index: file` error, so remove these lines,

```
$file_filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
$target_path  =  "Newfolder1";
$image_path = $target_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "filename";
$image_format = strtolower(pathinfo('filename', PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
```

So after user hits `view` button, you should process your form and display image like this,

```
// your code

if (isset($_POST['View']) ){
    $pdf=new fpdf();
    $pdf->ADDPage();
    $pdf->setfont('Arial','B', 16);  
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'sname',1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'sadd',1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'category',1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, 'scode',1,0,'c');


    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","school");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $sql="SELECT * FROM imagetable WHERE ID= '$_POST[search]'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
        die( "Could not execute sql: $sql"); 
    }

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    $image_path = $row['file'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $row['filename'];  // path should be like this, process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg
    $image_format = strtolower(pathinfo($image_path, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, $row['sname'],1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, $row['sadd'],1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Cell(40,10, $row['category'],1,0,'c');
    $pdf->Image($image_path,50,100,50,20,$image_format);
    $pdf->ln();
    $pdf->output();
}

// your code
```

Comment: brother it is now  opening the pdf but blank no image no data of that row only cells which i have defined in the starting

Comment: and also when iam removing the while loop from the my code for pdf it is showing same error of image extension

Comment: @IshankSainger You're fetching only one row from the table, so there's no need of `while` loop. Also check whether you're getting any row from the table or not, use `mysqli_num_rows()` function for that. I think you're not getting any row from the table.

Comment: it is showing image file is empty , and one thing     $image_path = $row['file'];  ----- this file should be path or file name

Comment: @IshankSainger `$image_path = $row['file'];` should have the full path of the image, not just directory or file name, like this  `process/upload/8/cdv_photo_001.jpg`

Comment: but i have tow fields where one is filename in which file exact name is stored and the other name is file where directory name is stored

Comment: @IshankSainger Well, then your `$image_path` should be like this, `$image_path = $row['file'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $row['filename'];`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: thanks a ton buddy again ........... and y iam getting 6 cells y isnt there is 3 cells for table attribute and three cell for there data i guess i have to crrct some order in pdf cells but still thanks a ton

Comment: @IshankSainger You're very welcome. :) Please read [the documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm) to see how you can format your cells.

Comment: @IshankSainger Glad to see it was resolved. Good job Rajdeep, *cheers*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks, happy holidays. :)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul You're welcome and thanks. Happy Holidays/New Year to you :)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34493363/dropdown-other-value-not-saving-to-database?noredirect=1#comment56730362_34493363 can u help with this?

Comment: @IshankSainger Sorry, I just saw your question. And I can see that you have solved it already. Cheers. :)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul ya just did it :)