# dropdown other value not saving to database

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

```
         <script type="text/javascript">
    function showfield(name){
      if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='other: <input type="text" name="other" />';
      else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
    }
    </script>
      <html>
            <head> 
              <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                            <link href = "css/bootstrap.min.css" rel = "stylesheet">
              <title> Insert</title>
            </head>
            <body> 

              <h1>Insert Data In to Db</h1>
              <form action="teachersubmit.php" method="post" id="form">
                <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value ="true" />

             <label>  School Code: <input type="text" name="scode" /></label>
             <label>  Category: <input type="text" name="category" /></label>
            <label>   name: <input type="text" name="sname" /></label>
             <label>  Address: <input type="text" name="sadd"></label><br>
            <label>   name:  <select name="gender" id="gender">
              <option value="male">male</option>
 <option value="female">female</option>
                   <option value="Other">Other</option>
            </select></label>
           <div id="div1"></div>


            <button type="submit" form="form" value="Submit">Submit</button>
    </form>

        if (isset($_POST ['submitted']) ){
         $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","school");
               if (mysqli_connect_errno())
          {
          echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
          }



                if(!empty($_POST['other'])) 
{

   $sname=$_POST['sname'];
$scode=$_POST['scode'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$sadd=$_POST['sadd'];
$gender=$_POST['other'];

  $sqlinsert= "INSERT INTO form1 (sname,scode,category,sadd,gender) VALUES ('$sname' , '$scode', '$category', '$sadd', '$gender')";

   if(!mysqli_query($con, $sqlinsert)){
    die ('not inserted');
    }}
    else{
$sname=$_POST['sname'];
$scode=$_POST['scode'];
$category=$_POST['category'];
$sadd=$_POST['sadd'];
$gender=$_POST['gender'];

    $sqlinsert= "INSERT INTO form1 (sname,scode,category,sadd,gender) VALUES ('$sname' , '$scode', '$category', '$sadd', '$gender')";

     if(!mysqli_query($con, $sqlinsert)){
        die ('not inserted');
         }

      }
```

Solved ..... thanks all of u for helping i just put the condition that if that hidden field is empty then take the dropdown value and if not then take the textbox value ......cheers :)

---

This is the database structure:

```
sname    varchar(100)   
category varchar(100)           
sadd     varchar(100)   
scode    varchar(20)
gender   varchar(100)
```

Comment: Be advised, **this code IS NOT safe**. Please, read [**How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: already updated it to the latest and still trying if finds anything useful will update it

Answer (score 1):

`Value` is missing in `option` that's the reason dropdown value not posting form form and not save into database

```
 <option>male</option>
 <option>female</option>
```

It would be

```
 <option value="male">male</option>
 <option value="female">female</option>
```

To check error in your query read

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Your code is open for sql injection . Read this to prevent it form it

[How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

**EDITED**

Data is not inserted because `sname,scode,category,sadd` are `integer type` in database and you are trying to insert `character`

ALter `sname,scode,category,sadd` filed as `varchar` into your database

Comment: `print_r($_POST)` and check what value you got and post you form post array

Comment: it is printing the the textbox value but y isn't saving it in to database?

Comment: echo  your query and paste your query here!! aslo check this to find out errro in your code http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: INSERT INTO form1 (sname,scode,category,sadd,gender) VALUES ('ds' , 'ds', 'ds', 'ds', 'Other')

Comment: Run this query directly into your phpmyadmin and check the error

Comment: no error but it is saving only other not the text box value of other

Comment: Check the datatype of every single of your values. Maybe you used an INT or something like this ?

Comment: @IseNgaRt may be you are correct !! It may be datatype problem

Comment: <label>  School Code: <input type="text" name="scode" /></label> only this is int rest of it are varchar

Comment: Then make all `sname,scode,category,sadd` varcare otherwise it will only get integer value

Comment: done and inserted values again but still it is saving other under gender field

Comment: then how was this print_r($_POST) was showing the text box value but that value is not inserting in datbase?

Comment: Check answer **EDITED** part!!

Comment: `varcare` doesn't seem like an actual data type. [**Varchar**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/char.html) on the other hand...

Comment: Run your query `INSERT INTO form1 (sname,scode,category,sadd,gender) VALUES ('ds' , 'ds', 'ds', 'ds', 'Other')` in phpmyadmin and check the error

Comment: 2 sname varchar(100) 
 3 category varchar(100) 
 4 sadd         varchar(100) 
 5 scode varchar(20)   
 6 gender varchar(100)

Comment: @Saty i did that tooooo but still no error in phpmyadmin

Comment: Edited your question also add your table structure into that